# Merge Two different Data Frame (like VLOOKUP)

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, lookup, vlookup

I have two data frame :

```
> head(df_Edges)  
  Source         Target     Type Weight
@kuabt        @_chuad Directed      1
@kuabt @arifsetia2013 Directed      1
@kuabt         @kuabt Directed      1
@kuabt     @chongbeng Directed      1
@kuabt     @billtay25 Directed      1
@kuabt        @gst183 Directed      1
```

and

```
> head(df_Nodes)
   Id          Label
73         @kuabt
148     @billtay25
168     @chongbeng
187 @nonvitaltooth
216        @gst183
244 @arifsetia2013
```

i want to change label in df_edge to be "Id number", so the result will be like this:

```
  Source         Target         Type Weight
   73            298     Directed      1
   73            244     Directed      1
   73             73     Directed      1
   73            168     Directed      1
   73            148     Directed      1
   73            216     Directed      1
```

I was trying like this,

```
df<-merge(df_Nodes, df_Edges, by.x = "Label", by.y = "Source")
```

but the result still the same like before.
so, how i can make it?
thanks.

Comment: Please format your data

Comment: How did you get 298 for the first row in expected?

Comment: format?can you explain? it's just head of df_nodes dataframe, actually it has more data..

Comment: @akrun I believe that it is further along in `df_Nodes`, not printed in the question.  To the questioner, you should change your example so that it is short and complete.  Don't include `_@chuad` (target 298) if it is not in `df_Nodes`.

Comment: oh.. i see.. :D, that's my mistake..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `merge` here, as you can do this with two applications of `match` directly:

```
df_Edges$Source <- df_Nodes$Id[match(df_Edges$Source, df_Nodes$Label)]
df_Edges$Target <- df_Nodes$Id[match(df_Edges$Target, df_Nodes$Label)]
df_Edges
##   Source Target     Type Weight
## 1     73     NA Directed      1
## 2     73    244 Directed      1
## 3     73     73 Directed      1
## 4     73    168 Directed      1
## 5     73    148 Directed      1
## 6     73    216 Directed      1
```

The `NA` value is because this row is missing from `df_Nodes` in your example.

Comment: You are using the same methodology as I showed with `match`.

Comment: @akrun Indeed I am, but for both columns, and giving the result the desired names.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `match` with `Map` to create new columns in 'df_Edges'.

```
df_Edges[c("Source", "Target")] <- Map(function(x,y) df_Nodes$Id[match(x,y)],
                      df_Edges[c("Source", "Target")], list(df_Nodes$Label))
df_Edges
##   Source Target     Type Weight
## 1     73     NA Directed      1
## 2     73    244 Directed      1
## 3     73     73 Directed      1
## 4     73    168 Directed      1
## 5     73    148 Directed      1
## 6     73    216 Directed      1
```

---

Or we can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df_Edges, df_Nodes, by = c(Target = "Label")) %>% 
          mutate(Target  = Id) %>%
          left_join(., df_Nodes, by = c(Source = "Label")) %>% 
          mutate(Source = Id.y) %>% 
          select(-matches("Id"))
#   Source Target     Type Weight
#1     73     NA Directed      1
#2     73    244 Directed      1
#3     73     73 Directed      1
#4     73    168 Directed      1
#5     73    148 Directed      1
#6     73    216 Directed      1
```